# NSOperationQueue never on main thread?

Tags: cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to get this right, so, the question I have is:

When I instantiate an NSOperationQueue like this:

> NSOperationQueue * operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

Then add an operation to it:

> [operationQueue addOperation:....];

Is the operation NEVER run on the main thread?

What tells me that any operations I add to the queue are run on a background thread 100% of the time and never on the main thread? Is it just the way NSOperationQueues are designed to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, operation queues (other than the main operation queue returned by `+[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`) are never serviced by the main thread. From the [`NSOperationQueue` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Operation queues usually provide the threads used to run their
>   operations. In OS X v10.6 and later, operation queues use the
>   libdispatch library (also known as Grand Central Dispatch) to initiate
>   the execution of their operations. As a result, operations are always
>   executed on a separate thread, regardless of whether they are
>   designated as concurrent or non-concurrent operations.